# Sending static values for woocommerce billing fields after certain shipping method is chosen

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am having a tough time trying to send static values for woocommerce address fields, when a certain shipping method is chosen. I am hiding fields, but I still need them to send static data, or in this example the shipping pickup point address.

Basically I would like to send static field values for address when a custom chooses a Pickup point as a shipping method, so he/she would not need to insert any additional information than needed.

I would like to use this code with this custom code - which hides fields on a certain shipping method.

```
<?php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'remove_billing_checkout_fields' );
function remove_billing_checkout_fields( $fields ) {
    // change below for the method
    $shipping_method ='itella_pp'; 
    // change below for the list of fields
    $hide_fields = array( 'billing_address_1', 'billing_address_2', 'billing_city', 'billing_state', 'billing_postcode', 'billing_company' );

    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    // uncomment below line and reload checkout page to check current $chosen_methods
    // print_r($chosen_methods);
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    foreach($hide_fields as $field ) {
        if ($chosen_shipping == $shipping_method) {
            $fields['billing'][$field]['required'] = false;
            $fields['billing'][$field]['class'][] = 'hide';
        }
        $fields['billing'][$field]['class'][] = 'billing-dynamic';
    }

    return $fields;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cart_update_script', 999 );
function cart_update_script() {
    if (is_checkout()) :
    ?>
    <style>
        .hide {visibility: hidden!important;}
    </style>
    <script>
        jQuery( function( $ ) {

            // woocommerce_params is required to continue, ensure the object exists
            if ( typeof woocommerce_params === 'undefined' ) {
                return false;
            }

            $(document).on( 'change', '#shipping_method input[type="radio"]', function() {
               
                $('.billing-dynamic').toggleClass('hide', this.value == 'itella_pp');
            });
        });
    </script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
?>
```

Here is what I have code wise so far to send static value. I plan to use wordpress add_filter. So basically I need to hardcode the address fields values if a pickup point shipping method is chosen. Should it be something like this?

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'send_static_values' );
function send_static_values ($fields) {
  $shipping_method ='itella_pp';
    global $woocommerce;
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    if ($chosen_shipping == $shipping_method) {
       $fields['billing_address_1']['value'] = 'Something 15';
       $fields['billing_city']['value'] = 'Something12';
       $fields['billing_state']['value'] = 'Something'; 
       $fields['billing_postcode']['value'] = '124712'; 
       $fields['billing_company']['value'] = 'Something Ltd';
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out the answer to this question myself. So to do that you just need to use add_filter to change the values and then output them.

Using this code the desired solution can be achieved.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_checkout_fields', 'send_static_values' );
function send_static_values ($fields) {
  $shipping_method ='yourshippingmethodvalue';
    global $woocommerce;
    $chosen_methods = WC()->session->get( 'chosen_shipping_methods' );
    $chosen_shipping = $chosen_methods[0];

    if ($chosen_shipping == $shipping_method)  {
       $fields['billing']['billing_address_1']['default'] = 'Aasa tee 1';
       $fields['billing']['billing_city']['default'] = 'Loo';
       $fields['billing']['billing_state']['default'] = 'Harjumaa'; 
       $fields['billing']['billing_postcode']['default'] = '74201'; 
      
    }

    return $fields;
}
```

If you want to add other fields, just find out the name of the field and add it like the other ones.
The 'default' just means, that it is the default value for the field. And if the fields are hidden before, then it send the values either way.